# NSMUtableArray adding objects by clicking on a button

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray

I am having problems to do show some data in a UITextView.. here´s the problem. I have a pickerview with two components: one with the products and the other one with the amount to be sold.

I also created a NSMutableArray and stored the price of each product. Added a button to do the calculation and actually this part so far is working just fine as when I click the button the result is showed in the UITextView.

The problem is that I want to show the total amount in U$ of the selected products, like, I select three products and when I click the button the result would show in the TextView.

I tried to do this way,but it didn´t work: I thought I´d create another NSMutableArray to store the products selections and when the user clicked the button it would give me the result.. but I couldn´t manage to add the products to the nsmutablearray, because I don´t know how to do it..

So, anyone could help??

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is that you don't know? How to add a object to a `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Well, I don´t know both: whether nsmutablearray will solve what I am trying to do and how to add a new object to nsmutablearray during app execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding objects to NSMutableArray you have to use the method "addObject".

```
[yourMutableArray addObject:yourObject];
```

Edit:

Declare your mutable array as an atribute.

In your header.

```
NSMutableArray *yourMutableArray;
```

Then you can use initiate it in your .m init as:

```
yourMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And then when you handle the button clicked action, add the object (without initiate it again).

luck!

Comment: I know it works this way, but what I am trying to understand and do is add object while the is running. Like when I click the button it adds a new object to the array, when I click add the same button it adds another one, and so on.

Comment: This is the way in wich you add an object to an array in runtime, you can't add objects in compile time, in compile time you define arrays. An how you link to the "button click" is other story, do you know how to do that?

Comment: well, if you know, and with the line for addobject, you should acomplish what you want.

Comment: Well I think yes, I know how to do it:   - (IBAction)adiciona {
        
    float quantFlt = [[quantidade objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
    float valorFlt = [[valor objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
    float final = quantFlt * valorFlt;
    
    
    //Mensagem com o resultado da venda
 NSString *teste = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"R$ %.2f.", final];
    
    
    mostra.text = teste;
}
 this is the button click 
    
    valor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [valor addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.70]];